# Why is np.dot much slower the first time it is called in a python session?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am trying to do series of big `np.dot(a,x)` operations, and the first one seems to take far longer than subsequent calls.  In my problem, `a` is tall [n x 2] and `x` is [2 x 1].  My big matrix `a` is constant, it is just `x` that is changing.  Here is a MWE:

```
import numpy as np

@profile
def do_work(a,x):
    tmp = np.dot(a,x)
    return tmp

@profile
def do_work_iter(a,x):
    tmp = np.dot(a,x)
    return tmp

if __name__=="__main__":

    n = 50000
    a = np.random.randn(n,2)
    x = np.random.randn(2,1)

    #
    tmp = do_work(a,x)

    #
    niter = 100
    for i in range(niter):
        x = np.random.randn(2,1)
        tmp = do_work_iter(a,x)
```

Using `line_profiler`, I get .155 s/call for the first call to `np.dot` and .00013 s/call for the subsequent ones.  Is there some setup/error checking that `numpy` is doing the first time here?  Is there a way I can bypass any of it?  Or is there some kind of searching for blas functions that is taking all of the time?

I also ran `profile` and it gives the following:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    0.000    0.000    1.514    1.514 {built-in method builtins.exec}
     1    0.000    0.000    1.514    1.514 <string>:1(<module>)
     1    0.000    0.000    1.514    1.514 speed_small.py:15(run)
   101    1.503    0.015    1.503    0.015 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.dot}
     1    0.000    0.000    1.491    1.491 speed_small.py:5(do_work)
   100    0.000    0.000    0.012    0.000 speed_small.py:10(do_work_iter)
```

so `numpy.core.multiarray.dot` is taking all of the time, it doesn't give much insight about anything further down the stack.

I am on Python 3.6 from Anaconda and have mkl installed (Windows 7).

Comment: I use [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler)  but my _guess_ would be that you're incurring the `import` overhead the first time. After that, The module is cached

Comment: @roganjosh Isn't the module included before the script comes to ```if __name__ == '__main__':``` part ?

Comment: It's an external module and nothing in your code suggests you're using it (EDIT:  that's a lie, you're using `@profile` decorator so I'll rethink) I don't know exactly what timings get bundled into the main library timings.

Comment: Loading of BLAS?